# Syntax error for the "elif" in the second task

Tags: python

```
task = input (' Hello! Welcome to Juan Robles program select task 1, 2 or  3. If you would like to exit the program Type 5 \n')


if (task == 1 ) : 
    print "Task 1 is here! \n"
    print "I can tell you if n is evenly divisible by m \n"
    print "Enter the following"
    n = input("Integer:")
    m = input("Integer:")
    evaluation = n % m
    if evaluation == 0:
    print n, "/", m, " evenly divides"
else:
    print n, "/", m, " Sorry, does not evenly divide. Try again!"




elif (task == 2 ): 
    print "Task 2 is here! \n"
    print "I can tell you if the number you enter is prime or not  \n"

    number=int(raw_input("Enter any number "))
if number <= 1:
    print "Sorry! It is not prime"
else:
    n=2
    check = True
    while n != m:
        if m%n == 0:
            print "Yeas! The number you entered is prime"
            check = False
            break
        n+=1
    if check == True:
            print "Yeas! The number you entered is prime"
```

The program gives me a `SyntaxError` for the `elif` in the second task. And when I input task 2, for some reason it goes right to the first one.

Comment: Please remember the advice you got on your first question concerning this code: Don't write `if (task == 1 ) :`, just use `if task == 1:` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `elif` has not outer if

your code is like

```
if:
....
....
else:
...
...
elif:
....
```

You have to write like

```
if:
....
....
elif:
...
...
else:
....
```

Comment: true, but this is not the case. clearly from print messages we see the first else should match inner if, not the if (task == 1 )

Comment: @Lafada are you refrering to task 2?

Comment: @DorothyBurch yes, your task 2 start with `elif` but where is outer `if` of `elif` ?

Comment: @Lafada fixed it. but still when i typed " task 2 ", it starts runing task 1 . what do you think is the problem.?

Comment: have you corrected indentation yet? please see the second answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

Correct the indentation in lines 12, 13, 14:

```
    if evaluation == 0:
    print n, "/", m, " evenly divides"
else:
    print n, "/", m, " Sorry, does not evenly divide. Try again!"
```

Should be:

```
    if evaluation == 0:
        print n, "/", m, " evenly divides"
    else:
        print n, "/", m, " Sorry, does not evenly divide. Try again!"
```